# Build up rating with png images

Tags: ios, swift

Since half star image is not available in emoji or unicode, I have decided to download full star and half star images in png format as follows.

[image]

[image]

However , I am stuck to build rate with these two single images.

I want to show 3.5 stars. Is it possible or is there an easy way?

I could able to put 5 image views next to each other and set each of them based on rating, but it sounds not efficient way of handling.

Comment: What you have tried post the code ?

Comment: @Spynet I could able to put 5 image views next to each other and set each of them based on rating, but it sounds not efficient way of handling. A lot of manual work is required in this approach.

Comment: it's ok but you need to show some part of code then only we find some solution

Comment: I think my approach is not efficient and manual work required, therefore, I need to know there is an easy way of handling this problem

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/star-rating-view

Comment: I do not want to use third party tools. I am about to building it my self as library to anyone to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173697/discussion-between-spynet-and-hotspring).

Comment: are you struggling with the logic of the rating system or how you can position the stars next to each other

Comment: @NaderBesada, yes exactly. I am planning to write a method, where you pass float number then, it will return you image. For example, if I pass 3.5, then it will return me 3 full stars and one half star as a uiimage.

Comment: Hint: Use UIView with Xib.

Comment: I am newbie on swift. Could you please illustrate in example?

Comment: Being new means you have to work harder to catch up by reading books and run a search day after day.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this on my phone so is probably not the best way to do it but you can improve the idea.

```
let stars = 3.5

let stackView = UIStackView()
//setup horizontal stackView

let oneStarImage = UIImage(named: "oneStar")
let halfStarImage = UIImage(named: "halfStar")

func addStarImages() {
    var value = stars
    while true {
        value -= 1
        if value >= 0 {
            print("Add 1 star")

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = oneStarImage

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)

        } else if value == -0.5 {
            print("Add half a star")

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = halfStarImage

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
            break
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
}

// Add 1 star
// Add 1 star
// Add 1 star
// Add half a star
```

Comment: where does `UIImage` come to the picture in this solution?

Comment: You can maybe use a horizontal stack view. Look at my updated answer